# How to convert Unicode text which looks like English to ASCII?

Tags: javascript, ruby, bash, unix, ascii

I have a text like "Previously" which looks English but has a non-ASCII characters in it:

[image]

What would be the easiest way to convert it to English text (so that "P" would be a latin capital letter P, for example) ?

For simplicity, let's assume that the non-English characters are Russian.
But, a more general solution will be much appreciated!

Preferable languages: Javascript, Ruby, Bash script.

Comment: are you trying to convert the words based solely on the visual similarly of letters in different alphabets?

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although some Cyrillic (and Greek) letters are identical with some Latin letters in graphic appearance (i.e., there is probably no difference in any font that contains both), there is no formal mapping defined between them. Thus, you would need to define the mapping yourself. For Russian, there is a rather limited number of such letters, so it would be a matter of a small mapping table. But if you wish to cover all of Unicode, there is a large numer of lookalikes and almost lookalikes, so the hard part would be to decide which characters are similar enough.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend [Unicode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unidecode) package, it will map Greek and Cyrillic letters to their closest ascii symbol and removes any diacritics:

```
unidecode('Lillı Celiné Никита Ödipus');
```

> 'Lilli Celine Nikita Odipus'

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem.  Н (in Никита) should be translated to H not N.  You are translating "sounds like".  Poster asked for "looks like".

Answer (score 1):

If the number of characters to be converted is small (e.g. Russian alphabet), then a simple dictionary mapping input characters to output characters would suffice.

Simply loop through the string and for each character look if it's in the dictionary and if yes, replace it with the replacement character stored in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The Russian government has provided an official list of [Cyrillic characters that look like Latin characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_registration_plates_of_Russia). You can use this list to construct a table. For the more general diacritic check you can use a [normalized form](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) and a filter if you need that

```
function Americanize(str){
   const lookup = {
      А:'A',В:'B',Е:'E',К:'K',М:'M',Н:'H',О:'O',
      Р:'P',С:'C',Т:'T',У:'y',Х:'X',а:'a',в:'B',
      е:'e',к:'K',м:'M',н:'H',о:'o',р:'p',с:'c',
      т:'T',у:'y',х:'x'
    };
    return Array.from(str.normalize('NFKD'))
       .filter(E => (lookup[E] ?? E).charCodeAt(0) < 128).join('');
}
```

This obviously leaves off many characters that can be interpreted as similar looking but not the same form ( И vs N )